# edit or add text in xml with R

Tags: r, xml

I have a large xml-Document (over 3.000 lines). Backround: My survey software allows the export as an xml file. To save some work, I would like to automate the translation of the questions into different languages (19!) and then add them into this xml. In the example below is 1 question in german and the translation in Englisch and Persian. What do I want to achieve:
Insert a child  <LANGENTRY LANG="en" VALUE=ru" text text text" />
and save the xml with the new child.

```
<QUESTIONBLOCK PLACE="5" TARGETLAYER="0" RANDOMIZED="false" NAME="" TUTOR="false">
<META KEY="KEEP_TOGETHER" VALUE="false"/>
<META KEY="METAKEY_ONLINE_QUESTION_SPACE" VALUE="DEFAULT"/>
<META KEY="METAKEY_VALIDATION_RULE" VALUE=""/>
<META KEY="METAKEY_TWO_COLUMN_PAPER" VALUE="false"/>
<EXPLANATION PLACE="1" NAME="[b]5. Seit wann wohnen Sie in Deutschland, Leipzig bzw. Ihrem 
Wohngebiet? Bitte tragen Sie das Jahr ein." TUTOR="false">
<META KEY="METAKEY_ONLINE_QUESTION_SPACE" VALUE="DEFAULT"/>
<INTLVAL KEY="NAME">
<LANGENTRY LANG="en" VALUE="[b]5. Since when do you live in Germany, Leipzig or the residential area 
you are living at the moment? Please enter the year. "/>
<LANGENTRY LANG="fa" VALUE="&#x200c;&#x640;  &#x627;&#x632; &#x686;&#x647; 
&#x632;&#x645;&#x627;&#x646;&#x6cc; &#x62a;&#x627;&#x6a9;&#x646;&#x648;&#x646; &#x62f;&#x631; 
&#x622;&#x644;&#x645;&#x627;&#x646; &#x628;&#x62a;&#x631;&#x62a;&#x6cc;&#x628; &#x62f;&#x631; 
&#x644;&#x627;&#x6cc;&#x67e;&#x632;&#x6cc;&#x6af; &#x6cc;&#x627; &#x645;&#x646;&#x637;&#x642;&#x647; 
&#x645;&#x633;&#x6a9;&#x648;&#x646;&#x6cc; &#x62e;&#x648;&#x62f; &#x632;&#x646;&#x62f;&#x6af;&#x6cc; 
&#x645;&#x6cc; &#x6a9;&#x646;&#x6cc;&#x62f;&#x61f;"/>
</INTLVAL>
</EXPLANATION>
```

This is what I have tried:
`xml_find_all(xml, xpath = "//LANGENTRY/@VALUE")%>%xml_text()` but I have no idea how to change existing text or add a new child?

Furthermore I also have to find the questions. In the example it is questionblock place "5". I would like to use a pipe or loop to process the questions one after the other and add the translations. Then I can import the completed XML back into the software.

I hope this is somehow clear ;)

Answer (score 3):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files, where you can pass parameters (language type and translated text) between R to stylesheet for transformation. You can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with the `xslt` package (sister to `xml2)`. Do note: XSLT is an industry language so is portable to other languages (Java, Python, PHP) and [executables](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) which do have parameter interfaces.

Specifically, run the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) template to copy XML as is and then bind parameters to new `LANGENTRY` node under `INTLVAL` node conditionally after searching for original text.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- INITIALIZE PARAMS -->
    <xsl:param name="orig_text"/>
    <xsl:param name="trans_lang"/>
    <xsl:param name="trans_text"/>
    
    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- ADD LANGENTRY NODES WITH BINDED PARAM VALUES -->
    <xsl:template match="INTLVAL">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       <xsl:if test = "ancestor::EXPLANATION[@NAME = $orig_text]">
            <LANGENTRY LANG="{$trans_lang}" VAL="{$trans_text}"/>
       </xsl:if>      
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**R** *(demonstrating with loop)*

```r
library(xml2)
library(xslt)

# READ XML AND XSLT
doc <- read_xml("Input.xml", package = "xslt")
style <- read_xml("Script.xsl", package = "xslt")

# TRANSLATION DATA
translations <- list(
                     list(orig = c("de", "[b]5. Seit wann wohnen Sie in Deutschland, Leipzig bzw. Ihrem  Wohngebiet? Bitte tragen Sie das Jahr ein."),
                          other = c("en", "[b]5. Since when do you live in Germany, Leipzig or the residential area  you are living at the moment? Please enter the year. ")),
                     list(orig = c("de", "[b]5. Seit wann wohnen Sie in Deutschland, Leipzig bzw. Ihrem  Wohngebiet? Bitte tragen Sie das Jahr ein."),
                          oth = c("fa", "ـ  از چه  زمانی تاکنون در  آلمان بترتیب در  لایپزیگ یا منطقه  مسکونی خود زندگی  می کنید؟")),
                     list(orig = c("de", "Die Sanftmütigen werden die Erde erben"),
                          other = c("en", "The meek shall inherit the earth")),
                     list(orig = c("de", "Die Sanftmütigen werden die Erde erben"),
                          other = c("fr", "Les doux hériteront de la terre")),
                     list(orig = c("de", "Sein oder Nichtsein; das ist hier die Frage"),
                          other = c("en", "To be, or not to be: that is the question")),
                     list(orig = c("de", "Sein oder Nichtsein; das ist hier die Frage"),
                          oth = c("es", "¡Ser, o no ser, es la cuestión!"))
                    )          
               
# LOOP THROUGH TRANSLATIONS AND PASS IN PARAMS FOR TRANSFORMATION
for (t in translations) {
   doc <- xml_xslt(doc, style, 
                   params=list(orig_text = t$orig[2],  # LIST NAME MUST MATCH XSLT PARAM
                               trans_lang = t$oth[1],  # LIST NAME MUST MATCH XSLT PARAM
                               trans_text = t$oth[2])  # LIST NAME MUST MATCH XSLT PARAM
                  )
}
                    
# SAVE EDITED DOC TO FILE           
output <- write_xml(doc, "Output.xml")
```

---

**Input XML** *(no LANGENTRY nodes)*

```xml
<QUESTIONBLOCK PLACE="5" TARGETLAYER="0" RANDOMIZED="false" NAME="" TUTOR="false">
  <META KEY="KEEP_TOGETHER" VALUE="false" />
  <META KEY="METAKEY_ONLINE_QUESTION_SPACE" VALUE="DEFAULT" />
  <META KEY="METAKEY_VALIDATION_RULE" VALUE="" />
  <META KEY="METAKEY_TWO_COLUMN_PAPER" VALUE="false" />
  <EXPLANATION PLACE="1" NAME="[b]5. Seit wann wohnen Sie in Deutschland, Leipzig bzw. Ihrem  Wohngebiet? Bitte tragen Sie das Jahr ein." TUTOR="false">
    <META KEY="METAKEY_ONLINE_QUESTION_SPACE" VALUE="DEFAULT" />
    <INTLVAL KEY="NAME">
    </INTLVAL>
  </EXPLANATION>
  <EXPLANATION PLACE="1" NAME="Die Sanftmütigen werden die Erde erben">
    <META KEY="METAKEY_ONLINE_QUESTION_SPACE" VALUE="DEFAULT" />
    <INTLVAL KEY="NAME">
    </INTLVAL>
  </EXPLANATION>
  <EXPLANATION PLACE="1" NAME="Sein oder Nichtsein; das ist hier die Frage">
    <META KEY="METAKEY_ONLINE_QUESTION_SPACE" VALUE="DEFAULT" />
    <INTLVAL KEY="NAME">
    </INTLVAL>
  </EXPLANATION>
</QUESTIONBLOCK>
```

**Output XML** *(new LANGENTRY nodes)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QUESTIONBLOCK PLACE="5" TARGETLAYER="0" RANDOMIZED="false" NAME="" TUTOR="false">
  <META KEY="KEEP_TOGETHER" VALUE="false"/>
  <META KEY="METAKEY_ONLINE_QUESTION_SPACE" VALUE="DEFAULT"/>
  <META KEY="METAKEY_VALIDATION_RULE" VALUE=""/>
  <META KEY="METAKEY_TWO_COLUMN_PAPER" VALUE="false"/>
  <EXPLANATION PLACE="1" NAME="[b]5. Seit wann wohnen Sie in Deutschland, Leipzig bzw. Ihrem  Wohngebiet? Bitte tragen Sie das Jahr ein." TUTOR="false">
    <META KEY="METAKEY_ONLINE_QUESTION_SPACE" VALUE="DEFAULT"/>
    <INTLVAL KEY="NAME">
      <LANGENTRY LANG="en" VAL="[b]5. Since when do you live in Germany, Leipzig or the residential area  you are living at the moment? Please enter the year. "/>
      <LANGENTRY LANG="fa" VAL="ٜـ  از چه  زمانی تاکنون در  آلمان بترتیب در  لایپزیگ یا منطقه  مسکونی خود زندگی  می کنید؟"/>
    </INTLVAL>
  </EXPLANATION>
  <EXPLANATION PLACE="1" NAME="Die Sanftmütigen werden die Erde erben">
    <META KEY="METAKEY_ONLINE_QUESTION_SPACE" VALUE="DEFAULT"/>
    <INTLVAL KEY="NAME">
      <LANGENTRY LANG="en" VAL="The meek shall inherit the earth"/>
      <LANGENTRY LANG="fr" VAL="Les doux hériteront de la terre"/>
    </INTLVAL>
  </EXPLANATION>
  <EXPLANATION PLACE="1" NAME="Sein oder Nichtsein; das ist hier die Frage">
    <META KEY="METAKEY_ONLINE_QUESTION_SPACE" VALUE="DEFAULT"/>
    <INTLVAL KEY="NAME">
      <LANGENTRY LANG="en" VAL="To be, or not to be: that is the question"/>
      <LANGENTRY LANG="es" VAL="¡Ser, o no ser, es la cuestión!"/>
    </INTLVAL>
  </EXPLANATION>
</QUESTIONBLOCK>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as follows, but there's an issue with the HTML entities, I don't why they are substituted.

```
library(xml2)

xml <- read_xml("waschi.xml")

x <- xml_new_root("LANGENTRY")
langentry <- xml_find_first(x, "//LANGENTRY")
xml_set_attr(langentry, "LANG", "ru")
xml_set_attr(langentry, "VALUE", "text text text")

intlval <- xml_find_first(xml, "//INTLVAL")
xml_add_child(intlval, langentry)

write_xml(xml, "waschi_new.xml")
```